# IronPython error, "'TextBox' object has no attribute 'text'" when using a ShowDialog() method created in SharpDevelop

Tags: forms, textbox, ironpython, sharpdevelop

I am trying to call a form designed in SharpDevelop within another IDE. I get the following error message: 'TextBox' object has no attribute 'text'. This happens when I run the script which includes the lines shown below in the other IDE. Is the problem in the script itself or in the Form1 class written in SharpDevelop? How can I resolve this?

```
import myform
import System

f = myform.Form1()
if f.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK:
    dx = f._directionx.text
    dy = f._directiony.text
    dz = f._directionz.text
    nb = f._nbofiterations.text
    w = f._width.text
    h = f._height.text
```

Comment: Is this a warning your IDE is giving you or an error you get when you run your code?

Comment: yes I will make it clearer in the question thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it appears that you're using IronPython (the `System.Windows.Forms` gave it away) I'm guessing that your `TextBox` is a Forms element.

If this is so, you need the `.Text` property - everything (properties, functions/methods that I know of) in the .NET library starts with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score -1):

change .text to .Text
dx = f._directionx.Text
and so on
C sharp is case sensitive language

Comment: in what way does that add anything, it is less clear but contains the same content as the accepted answer.